# Display format is not visible as required?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura

Following is my apex class code.

```
 public static List<ReportEvent> TransactionalSecurityTmonth()
{
  return[SELECT Name, QueriedEntities, Format, EventSource, NumberOfColumns, Operation, EventIdentifier, PolicyOutcome, Username, format(EventDate) FROM ReportEvent WHERE EventDate = THIS_MONTH];
 }
```

and Following is my Component code.

Event Date

```
       <th scope="row">
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:2rem" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.EventDate}</div>
  </th>
```

Here i want my format to be displayed in dd-mm-yy year fomat i.e event date although the query output is correct but it is not displayed as it is in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly referring to date using `{!v.EventDate}` will show ***Raw*** format. You can use [lightning:formattedDateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedDateTime/example) for appropriately formatting according to your need using its [attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedDateTime/specification). Below is the example:

```
<ol class="slds-list_ordered">
    <li>{!v.EventDate}</li>
    <li><lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!v.EventDate}"/></li>
    <li>
        <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!v.EventDate}"
                                     year="2-digit"
                                     month="2-digit"
                                     day="2-digit"/>
    </li>
</ol>
```

This will return below respectively:

> 1. date - Mon Sep 23 2019 20:46:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) .
> 2. 23 Sep, 2019 .
> 3. 23/09/19 .

Comment: Thanks It works fine but i have a problem with my csv file download

Answer (score 0):

The format of the dates in salesforce (how dates are shown in pages and layouts) depends on the locale configuration of the user.

Here you have a list of the Locales and time formats from salesforce help: 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_date_time_format.htm&type=5

If it's **vital** to have it in dd-mm-yy you will have to do it yourself (play with decomposing the date into day, month and year and then concatenate them).